# lodash's _.memoize with typescript methods

Tags: typescript, decorator, lodash

Does anyone have any experience incorporating lodash's memoize function with a typescript method?

I know typescript supports decorators but I've been having a bit of trouble understanding them.

I created an easy test code to modify with lodash wired to make explaining the solution easier:

https://codepen.io/thinkbonobo/pen/XKyaKY?editors=0010

I'd like to memoize run so that it returns the answer without the forced `wait`. If it is successfully memoized it will return "`MEMOIZED!!! :)`"

```
  run() {
    return this.doSomeProcessing();
  }
```

(N.B., I would suggest while coding to comment out the wait function so it doesn't give the synchronous lag from it as the program tries to run)

Comment: Please include all code necessary to understand the question on Stack Overflow itself, rather than on a third-party site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily memoize `run` with the `once` function https://lodash.com/docs#once:

```
   run = _.once(() => {
     return this.doSomeProcessing();
   });
```

Of course this makes it a member instead of a method [but that's okay](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html).

Comment: legit! making it an member is a great solution... still I do wish I could have used a decorator to solve this....

Answer (score 1):

A simple and elegant solution for have `@memoize()` decorator:

```
function memoize() {
    return function (target: any, functionName: string) {
      target[functionName] = _.memoize(target[functionName]);
    };
}
```

Live example: http://codepen.io/fabien0102/pen/KgPrOy?editors=0012

Answer (score 1):

[fabien0102's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39225150/178551) can easily be improved to support getters:

```
export function memoize() {
  return function (target: any, functionName: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    if (descriptor.get) descriptor.get = _.memoize(descriptor.get, function<T>(this: T):T { return this; });
    else descriptor.value= _.memoize(descriptor.value);
  };
}
```